# How to proof such propositions

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, quantifiers

let $P(x,y): x - 7y = 5$ and $Q(x,y): x-3 \geq y + 11$ 
$\exists x \forall y, Q(x,y)$  
$\exists x \exists y, P(x,y) \land \neg Q(x,y)$  
$\forall x \exists y, P(x,y) \geq Q(x,y)$

How de we prove if these propositions are true or false, I know when a ($\forall x, P$) proposition is false you can prove it by showing that ($\exists x, \neg P$) is true, and to prove ($\forall x, P$) is true you have to use a detailed demonstration, and to prove ($\exists x, P$) you just show one example where the equation is true.
However in these cases I really have no idea how to prove such propositions.

Comment: Is there a typo: $Q(x,y)$ does not contain the variable $y$ in its specification?

Comment: @user2661923 yes sorry I just corrected it Thank you!

Comment: @Stacker you converted them to their negation form but I don't see how this answer my question (don't mean to be ungrateful), is there something missing?

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your question. For the first one you find an x such that for all y, Q(x,y) holds. So one x where Q(x,y) is true for ALL y. No such x exists, so the first statement is false.

Comment: @Stacker Yep that's exactly what I thought but how de we prove that

Comment: "Suppose there exists an x such that for all y, Q(x,y) is true. Then $x-3\ge y+11$ for all y. But choose y=x-13. Then $x-3\ge x-2$ means that $0\ge 1$, which is false. So there cannot exist such an x." Is one possible way you could do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To disprove the first one set y = x.
To determine the second one, use the equation in P to reduce Q to a single variable and make your decision.
Explain why the third one is nonsense.

Comment: Thank you but what do you mean by "use the equation in P to reduce Q to a single variable" I don't get it

Comment: @Dom.  P is an equation.  Solve for x in terms of y.  Use that value for x in Q to get an inequality in y.

Comment: Is that a proper explanation why it's true? We have $x - 7y = 5$ and $x - 3 < y + 11$. Therefore $y = (x-5) / 7$ from $P$  
\begin{align*}
 &x-3 < (x-5) / 7 +11 \\
 &7x -21 < x + 72 \\
 &6x < 93 \\
 & x < 93 / 6 \\
\end{align*}

 Suppose $x = 5$. Therefore $y = 0 / 7 \Leftrightarrow y = 0$. We conclude the porposition is True because such $x$ and $y$ exists